# Full width div doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, format, position, containers

> **I am creating a site and often I'm getting a fairly big amount of bugs.**

What I want to fix now is that my div doesn't appear on the screen.

My code:

**1)** *index.html*

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
...
<div class="content">
    <div class="titl">
        <a class="atitle" href="#" target="_self">test</a>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**2)** *style.css*

```
div.titl {
    width: 100%;
    color: #414042;
    height: 50px;
    transition: .25s;
}
```

So the div called titl was used to appear and be at the very top of the page, but I only get the "test" line there.

What have I tried? Well, using the `position: absolute;` which didn't work.

**EDIT**: My `a.atitle` code:

```
a.atitle {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    transition: .25s;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: absolute;
}

a.atitle:hover {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #414042;
}

a.atitle:visited {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FF6E4E;
}
```

Comment: You div.titl is there. You can change `color` to `background-color` in `div.titl` and then will see the div clearly.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Should I present my a.atitle CSS code? May be it is the problem

Comment: Please run the code snippet I answered below. When the color change to background-color, the div was shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div.titl {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #414042; /* Change from color to background-color */
  height: 50px;
  transition: .25s;
}

a.atitle {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  transition: .25s;
  font-size: 32px;
  position: absolute;
}

a.atitle:hover {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #414042;
}

a.atitle:visited {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FF6E4E;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="titl">
    <a class="atitle" href="#" target="_self">test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok now it works, thanks! Have no clue why it didn't work some time ago

Comment: @KViiTEN Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-color` in place of `color` like:

```
div.titl {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #414042;
    height: 50px;
    transition: .25s;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Should I present my a.atitle CSS code? May be it is the problem

Comment: I checked it and its working, just change color to background-color, you can check this fiddle also https://jsfiddle.net/deepgagan/8j21rhky/1/